# How to remove everything between quotation marks in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

How do I remove everything between and including single quotes in Unix/Linux?

Example:
Input : `WHERE EnodeB_Fin    Date_Time_Fin >= '2022-03-15 00:00:00'`
Output : `WHERE EnodeB_Fin    Date_Time_Fin >=`

Comment: In what way is the input delivered? In a regular file? As the output of some command? In a variable? Please [edit] and be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the text in a file:

```
$ sed < file "s/'.*'//"
WHERE EnodeB_Fin Date_Time_Fin >=
```